# find polynomial equation from array with matlab

Tags: matlab, equation, polynomial-math

I've some [x.mat](http://pro.ellip6.com/SebastienForum/x.mat) and [y.mat](http://pro.ellip6.com/SebastienForum/y.mat).

And I would like to find the polynomial equation from this.

I've tried

`p = polyfit(x,y,3);`

with  `y2 = p(1)*x.^3 + p(2)*x.^2 + p(3)*x`

but my `y2` is not equal to the original `y` . What is wrong ?
Thanks you

Comment: Shouldn't you also have p(4)? Have you tried y2 = p(1)*x.^3 + p(2)*x.^2 + p(3)*x + p(4) ?

Comment: Instead of calculating `y2` by hand, you can do `y2 = polyval(p, x)`. Then to check the fit, do `plot(x, y2, x, y, '.r')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As radarhead wrote in his comment, you forgot the coefficient of zero degree (`p(4)` here).

Assuming `x` and `y` are vectors of same length `n`, `polyfit(x,y,n-1)` will return a vector containing the coefficients of the interpolating polynomial (of degree `n`-1) in descending order.

Then, the value of the interpolating polynomial at a point `z` will be given by:

```
p(1)*z^3 + p(2)*z^2 + p(3)*z + p(4)
```

Don't forget `p(4)`! As Bas suggested, you can use the `polyval` function to easily compute the value of a polynomial at a a given point:

```
polyval(p,z);
```

To illustrate this, see the code below, which generates 4 data points, plots those points and the polynomial interpolating them:

```
n = 4;
x = sort(rand(n,1));
y = rand(n,1);
p = polyfit(x,y,n-1);
figure
hold on
plot(x,y,'bo');
xx=linspace(x(1),x(end),100);
plot(xx,polyval(p,xx),'r');
hold off
```

[image]